# value of counter variable is zero in bash script

Tags: bash, variables, counter, addition

```
filecount=0
if [ -e "$filename$ext" ]
  then
   ls -l $filename$ext
   scp $filename$ext t2flex@ccfilesvr:/home/t2flex/.
   mv  $filename$ext $filename"_"$d$done
   echo $filename$ext secure copied to ccfilesvr
   filecount=$((filecount+1))
else
   echo "$filename$ext Not found in $path."
fi | tee >> $logfile
# -----------------------------------------------------
if [ -e "$filenam1$ext" ]
    then
     ls -l $filenam1$ext
     scp $filenam1$ext t2flex@ccfilesvr:/home/t2flex/.
     mv -f $filenam1$ext $filenam1"_"$d$done
     echo "$filenam1$ext secure copied to ccfilesvr"
     filecount=$((filecount+1))
else
     echo "$filenam1$ext Not found in $path."
fi 
# ----------------------------------
echo "Number of files to transfer into ccfilesvr: $filecount" >> $logfile
if [ $filecount -ge 1 ]
  then
   echo "Files ready to upload to T2. Entering ccfilesvr..."
   ssh t2flex@ccfilesvr . t2flexXfer.shl
else
  echo "No files to upload. Entering ccfilesvr to download charges."
   ssh t2flex@ccfilesvr . t2flexXfer.shl
fi
echo "Number of files to transfer into ccfilesvr: $filecount">> $logfile
```

This below is the output of the above..  I'm giving only the portion of the code that is giving me reason to retire!

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 455132 Feb 21 14:14 CC_T2_PERSON.txt
CC_T2_PERSON.txt secure copied to ccfilesvr
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 107314 Feb 21 14:14 CC_T2_CAMPUSBOX.txt
CC_T2_CAMPUSBOX.txt secure copied to ccfilesvr
Number of files to transfer into ccfilesvr: **0**
No files to upload.
```

Why is the counter always coming out as "0" for me?

Comment: I tried to bold the "0" above and asterisk came out.  Disregard **. Also disregard the | tee $logfile   ...I wanted to remove that for purposes of readability,  but forgot.

Comment: The `tee` command (or rather the pipe used to connect its input to the output of the `if` statement) would appear to be the problem. You are incrementing `filecount` in a  subprocess.

Comment: Add a debugging echo after incrementing filecount.

Comment: Okay thank you. I'll Add a debugging echo after incrementing filecount.  I'll not pipe tee the script ...  I'll use redirects >>.

Comment: PERFECT!!! Thank you!
File count is: 1 File count is: 2
Number of files to transfer into ccfilesvr: 2
Files ready to upload to T2. Entering ccfilesvr...

Answer (score 1):

The comment from chepner is the right diagnosis.

Replace this :

```
fi | tee >> $logfile
```

With this :

```
fi > >(tee >> $logfile)
```

What is the difference?

When piping a statement with `|`, the "left" part of the pipe is executed in a subshell, and a subshell cannot (no way) modify a variable in the parent shell.  The assigned value is lost when the subshell ends, returning control to the parent shell (living in a separate memory section of your computer).  What makes this easy to miss is that a subshell inherits an identical copy of all variables from the parent shell, so you do not clearly see a subshell is being launched.

One way to see it in action is to output "$BASHPID", which reflects the current subshell PID number (contrary to "$$" which reflects the main shell).

By using a process substitution (`> >(tee >> $logfile)`), the `if` statement is executed in the main shell, and `tee` is in a subshell, so the part that is important to you (the one with assignments) is what stays in the main shell.

I do not know of many drawbacks to process substitution compared to standard pipes.  They can be nested (which may become less readable than a pipe) to achieve multiple stages.  They exist in the "output" variety (`>()`) and "input" variety (`<()`).  Process substitutions result in the creation of FIFOs (special files), and the shell transforms the expression into a file name that can be read from or written to (depending on type), so they can basically be used everywhere a filename would be accepted.